# Why did Eisav say "red" twice?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, food, words, color, parashat-toldot

[Genesis 25:30](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8220#v30) says:

> ... הַלְעִיטֵנִי נָא מִן **הָאָדֹם הָאָדֹם** הַזֶּה ...
>
> ... "Pour into [me] some of this **red, red** [pottage] ..."

Why did Eisav feel the need to say "red" twice?

Comment: Perhaps add a source/link to make it easier for others to find an answer. This could help on all of your recent questions.

Comment: You could just write breishis 6:14 or whatever the pasuk actually is. A link helps a lot, but a source is close to mandatory. :-)

Comment: for the next ones I did it. if you could help by adding it would be appreciated I will get back to it

Comment: even linking to the perek on chabad.org helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In a *midrash*: Why did he repeat? *Esav* found *Yaakov* preparing lentils for his father in a dish, and told him "feed me" [=*hal'iteni na min haadom*]. He said, "wait, I'll prepare you another dish. I prepared this one for my father and don't want to cancel my *mitzva*. But if you're willing to sell your birthright, I'll give you my father's dish, which I'm allowed to do in order to purchase a *mitzva*. Otherwise, wait". And *Esav* replied, "I want only this dish [=*haadom haze*], for it's fat and good". And that's why he said *hal'iteni na min haadom haadom haze*: "I want this one, as it's fat, and will sell you the birthright".

— *Tol'dos Yitzchak*, by *Rav Yitzchak Karo* (uncle of the *Bes Yosef*), in my own free translation

Comment: In this case, a phrase break occurs between the two _ha'adom_s. is that license _midrashi_ or is it also the grammatical parsing?

Comment: @WAF, the cantillation mark on the first _haadom_ is a continuing one, not a pause.

Comment: can you provide a source or link to the original midrash?

Comment: @Mark, nope: I saw it only in the _Tol'dos Yitzchak_.

Answer (score 3):

I think it just shows Eisav's infatuation with the food. The redness is was draws him to it. So the pasuk is describing his words in a way for us to understand his thoughts, i.e. "The red, red stuff," all I care about is how appetizing and juicy it looks.

Comment: Good answer, but I think that the pasuk is recording what Eisav actually said. He himself doubled the word, not the Torah on his behalf. But you're right that the reason for his double language was his intense desire for the "red stuff". See [Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34563&st=&pgnum=122).

Comment: Yea, the Radak says it nicely. But I would beg to differ about the Torah's quotations. I take the approach that the Torah is written in a literary way and not a historical way. Therefore it chooses to tell stories and recount episodes in a way fitting for its purposes, and not necessarily in historically accurate ways. There are many literary devices employed  by the Torah on a regular basis, within quotations as well as narratives. At least that's my opinion. How else do you understand personification of God in instances like "etzba elohim" and the like? Metaphorically and not literally.

Comment: From last week's parsha, Chazal comment on Eliezer's repetition of his story to Lot, and how he says אולי without the ו, the second time, indicating that he was feeling אלי, about himself, and that he had a daughter, etc. There it's not a question of accurately quoting him but rather how the Torah writes something. It intentionally left out the ו to teach something.

Comment: Yes, the Torah uses literary devices. There are metaphorical references, idiomatic expressions, etc. But, this in no way compromises its historical accuracy. Just because it says "God took them out of Egypt with a mighty hand" and God does not physically have a hand, does not mean that that account is historically false. The same if I would say, "Stuffed-crust pizza rocks my world," I would not be considered lying on any account even though the pizza does not literally rock the world...

Comment: ...However, if I say "Let me tell you what my friend said; he said as follows" and I don't continue with his exact words, then I am being historically inaccurate. And while people don't mind when other people paraphrase things (as who can remember *exactly* what someone else said), many would find it problematic if the Torah did so. Thus, when the Torah writes "Eisav said etc., " I believe he is being quoted for his exact words. (Of course, in cases where things were not said in Hebrew, the Torah must translate.)...

Comment: ...R' Yaakov Kaminetzky goes so far as to say that the Torah quotes people's exact expressions with the grammar they used, even if the cantillation setup of the verse would usually require changing the grammar. (Of course, the Torah can feel free to spell things however it likes to teach whatever moral lessons it needs to.)

Comment: Why is it problematic to say that the Torah doesn't quote people verbatim?

Comment: Many will insist that the Torah is in fact inerrant and free of factual error. Like I said, it may use idiomatic expressions and metaphors. But quoting someone as saying something that they did not exactly say? What kind of literary device is that?

Comment: As I said, the Torah is not a historical account but rather a book of guidelines from God. If Jacob never had that conversation, does it matter? To me, no. What matters in my opinion is that God wants you to learn that story (and learn from it) and live your life accordingly. Yakov had certain character traits and Esav had others. Therefore, we Jews should do certain things. I'm not assuming to understand why the Torah is written exactly as it is in every detail, but I do believe much of the stories and content may not have occurred at all, or at least not exactly as they are recounted.

Comment: Ok. I was just explaining the other side. I don't think you are necessarily stepping out of any bounds here. Rambam would perhaps agree with you. I, however, prefer to take what would be the more "traditionalist" viewpoint on this matter. See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14369&st=&pgnum=121).

Comment: Thanks for the source @jake. I wouldn't have thought Abarbanel would have gone in that direction. I think that approach is problematic, because if you say it's all historical truth you have a problem when you want to explain Hoshea or Shir Hashirim. Suddenly those are allegorical? How do you know where to draw the line? And what about historical inaccuracies or contradictions with scientific and archaeological evidence. Yes there are answers, but the whole involvement of answering them is useless or intellectually dishonest.

Comment: See this discussion: http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2011/08/historical-records-vs-dramatic-accounts.html. Instead, I prefer the approach which sees the Torah in a literary light. The question is not whether it happened like it's told or not, that's irrelevant. The questions is what is written and what does that mean to me. Parts may be based on historical events, parts may be an accurate depiction, parts may be dramatized and parts may be pure fiction. It doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts was that it reminds me of the 'two bloods' of pesach and brit milah. I asked a scholar if this was the connection and he said yes. I am still pondering the deeper implications of this.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!