# Why is Jacob idolized and not villainised?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, sin, parashat-toldot, sheker-false

I've just read the story of Jacob and Esau (Bereishis ch. [25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/false/aid/8220/jewish/Chapter-25.htm) and [27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/false/aid/8222/jewish/Chapter-27.htm)), and I fail to understand why Jacob is consistently portrayed and idolized as a protagonist and a hero - based on what I've read, I consider him treacherous and evil character.

This is mostly based on his treatment towards Esau; when his famished [and apparently dying?] brother came to him and asked him for food, his reply was to demand the forfeiture of Esau's birthright. When his dying father wished to bless Esau, he lied to him and told him that he was Esau in order to steal the blessing.

He (and his mother) are deceitful and manipulative, yet I have not found a negative word on them - in fact, after Jacob robbed Esau of his birthright, it is said that Esau 'spurned' his birthright, shifting the blame to Esau. Jacob is idolized to the point that the entire Kingdom of Israel is named after him, and I just don't understand why; his actions make me detest him.

Why is Jacob, despite his treacherous deeds, portrayed by the Bible as a hero?

Comment: Daniel, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll poke around and find other information that interests you, perhaps including our 105 other questions about the [tag:Patriarchs]. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22663/2 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11410/2

Comment: @Daniel if when I learned each of the incidents, I learned the oral law's explanation of the event as not a deception, then my complete view of the event is that he is NOT presented as a deceiver. Is your question "why would the text as literal text present a superficial story which could be read as having Jacob be the bad guy" or are you limited in your personal understanding to the literal text and you are asking about "our" reaction to Jacob within a larger theological context?

Comment: @Dan, I think that an excellent answer to the question as stated would address your second option first and then your first option.

Comment: @Dan All I know about the story is what I've read from the literal text, so I suppose I'm limited in that manner, and I'd indeed appreciate an answer to the second option you provided. I apologize; I should have made my intent clearer.

Comment: Daniel, I really don't think you have anything to apologize for, FTR. The question is clear enough as it is, IMO. Like I said, an excellent answer would explain a traditional Jewish approach to understanding the text and would then also address why the text was written in a way that, read by itself, seems to point in the opposite ethical direction. (ping @Dan)

Comment: @Daniel, consider the possibility that in the lentil-stew incident, Eisav was "dying" in the sense that your teenager will just *die* if he doesn't get his own car (or cell phone, or iPad, or whatever), not that he was actually dying.  Also, Yaakov didn't keep him from eating; he just said that if you want some of mine rather than getting your own, there's a price.  The incident with his father is far more troubling to me.  Anyway, thanks for bringing your question here, and welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's an interesting interpretation, and I certainly agree that the incident with Isaac is more troubling. I just found it rather cruel to respond to your hungry brother by saying "First sell me your birthright," and it's clearly not a fair or reasonable trade for stew.

Comment: Perhaps it's not so cruel if your bigger, stronger brother has been bullying you for years.  I'm not saying that's what happened; I just find it useful to always look for alternative possibilities.

Comment: Moderator's note: Comments were too many and did not serve to improve or seek improvement of the question, so I've removed them. One that I removed but should not have (sorry!) had been posted by [Danno](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1362/danno) and read, in relevant part: here is a site which gives some explanation (and read the comments as well) http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/62002/jewish/The-Stolen-Blessings.htm

Comment: Re "I have not found a negative word on them - in fact, after Jacob robbed Esau of his birthright, it is said that Esau 'spurned' his birthright", I've always read 'spurned' in the verse there as indicating a subsequent action of Esau's rather than a narrator's interpretation of Esau's previously-depicted actions. That'd remove that aspect of your question. I don't know that my read is right, though.

Comment: @msh210: I don't remember who said it, but one of the commentaries say that the spurning was after Eisav ate. After he ate he reaffirmed that he had no need for the birthright, so it was not a distressed sale.  -- Also of interest: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11417/603

Comment: @msh210 Neither [OJPS](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0125.htm) or Artscroll reads like you. Note also the _etnacta_ of the pasuk.

Answer (score 4):

Although Issac was going to give Esau the beracha due to him being the elder, Rebecca knew from nevua that Jacob was the one who was supposed to get the beracha, Jacob spent his time studying Torah instead of hunting, and Esau did sell the birthright after all. Esau was not dying, for right after eating he up and walked away, he didn't care so much what would happen to his descendents as he said, "Behold, I am going to die, so why do I need this birthright?"

Jacob did not even want to deceive his father even if it was necessary for him to get the blessing he deserved, he only did so because of Rebecca.

Esau on the other hand was willing to kill Jacob over the blessing. Jacob showed by his actions in the following chapters that he was righteous. God had the entire Jewish nation come from him. So he was not a villain.

Comment: Rebecca was a neviah? Why wasn't she mentioned on the list of seven prophetesses (Megillah 14a)?

Comment: How do you know he had any descendants at the time for whom a birthright would be useful after his passing? If this was the only way to live, then I imagine his descendants would prefer being born to having a birthright.

Comment: @DoubleAA See Targum Onkelos (B'reishis 27:13, "*Alai is'amar bin'vu'a*..."), who writes that Rivka told Ya'akov that she knew through prophesy that no curse would fall upon Ya'akov from obeying her. Rashi (Makos 24a, s.v. *lo ragal al l'shono*) cites this as evidence that Rivka commanded Ya'akov to do this based on her prophesy. The Ramban (B'reishis, 27:7) also writes that Rivka had ru'ach hakodesh.

Comment: @DoubleAA Also, the Ramban writes (ibid., 27:4) that Rivka knew from the prophecy related to her earlier (see B'reishis 25:23) that Ya'akov was supposed to take the blessing, and that she had never told Yitzchak this prophecy. Perhaps Aaliyah was referring to this.

Comment: @Fred Indeed although still odd. see also http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/11/did-hashem-speak-directly-to-rivkah.html

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes. That's an interesting article. (Also, I apologize for my spelling in my first comment; I meant "prophecy", the noun not the verb).

Comment: @DoubleAA Interestingly, the Ramban here implies that she was told the prophecy by Shem or another prophet ("*ki hu gadol min hamagid li*"), unlike the apparent suggestion of direct prophecy in the Ramban referenced in the Parshablog article.

Comment: does justify the fact of:"This is mostly based on his treatment towards Esau; when his famished [and apparently dying?] brother came to him and asked him for food, his reply was to demand the forfeiture of Esau's birthright. When his dying father wished to bless Esau, he lied to him and told him that he was Esau in order to steal the blessing." ???